# How to extract numeric values from a column in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I need to extract only numeric values from a mix class of column. Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 score = c("1","0","1+AB","0,B","1,1","A","B","1,A","1","0,A+B,C"))

> df
   id   score
1   1       1
2   2       0
3   3    1+AB
4   4     0,B
5   5     1,1
6   6       A
7   7       B
8   8     1,A
9   9       1
10 10 0,A+B,C
```

from the column `score`, I only need the numeric values. If the value does not have numeric value, then the recoded value should be `0`. Also, if the numeric value is repeated as `1,1`, then only `1` will be recoded.

How can I get the desired output below.

```
> df
   id   score recoded_score
1   1       1   1
2   2       0   0
3   3    1+AB   1
4   4     0,B   0
5   5     1,1   1
6   6       A   0
7   7       B   0
8   8     1,A   1
9   9       1   1
10 10 0,A+B,C   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_extract` to extract the numeric part and then `coalesce` with 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(recoded_score = coalesce(as.numeric(str_extract(score, "\\d+")), 0))
```

-output

```
   id   score recoded_score
1   1       1             1
2   2       0             0
3   3    1+AB             1
4   4     0,B             0
5   5     1,1             1
6   6       A             0
7   7       B             0
8   8     1,A             1
9   9       1             1
10 10 0,A+B,C             0
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `parse_number` from `readr` which extract the first number of each string. Interestingly `,` does not separate the numbers, so to use it for `1,1` we have to change `,` by`;`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)


df %>% 
  mutate(score = str_replace(score, ",", ";"),
         recoded_score = parse_number(score),
         recoded_score = ifelse(is.na(recoded_score), score, recoded_score))
```

```
      id score   recoded_score
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        
 1     1 1       1            
 2     2 0       0            
 3     3 1+AB    1            
 4     4 0;B     0            
 5     5 1;1     1            
 6     6 A       A            
 7     7 B       B            
 8     8 1;A     1            
 9     9 1       1            
10    10 0;A+B,C 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** approach using `sub`

```
repl <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+.*", "", df$score))

df$recoded_score <- ifelse(is.na(repl), 0, repl)

df
   id   score recoded_score
1   1       1             1
2   2       0             0
3   3    1+AB             1
4   4     0,B             0
5   5     1,1             1
6   6       A             0
7   7       B             0
8   8     1,A             1
9   9       1             1
10 10 0,A+B,C             0
```